# Can a API effect Grapichs Quality

Tags: api, opengl, vulkan

I was looking to benchmarks and I can't see a difference. OpenGL 4.5 is same with Vulkan.  Can an API effect the graphics quality?

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answered in reasonable detail and length. The very short answer is: they share a lot of similarities but go very different ways in some respects e.g. memory management. Vulkan is designed to let you get the most out of currently available graphics hardware, while OpenGL abstracts away a lot of what you would have to do in Vulkan manually. Neither is necessarily or worse better than the other - they both exist in their own right and can be chosen according to your requirements.

Comment: Both APIs will connect to the same hardware, the biggest difference is that vulkan exposes a lot of the bookkeeping that openGL APIs must do behind the scenes.

Comment: @thokra I understand the grapichs are same. But if garpichs are same then wyh people using different API's ?!

Comment: @ratched freak I understand the grapichs are same. But if garpichs are same then wyh people using different API's ?!

Comment: @HopelesDeveloper: Because they offer varying degrees of control over how the application "talks" to the GPU. With Vulkan, you have to do many things *yourself* that would be done *for you* by an OpenGL implementation. Doing it yourself in Vulkan allows for great control over many details of what an OpenGL implementation hides from you. This way, you can minimize application-driver interaction dramatically and thus get the most performance - if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @HopelesDeveloper: OpenGL trades control for convenience by shifting work from the developer to the OpenGL implementation (usually part of a graphics driver package). This means that you don't have to bother with a lot of tedious detail but on the other hand, you depend on the implementation to do that job well for you. If the implementation sucks, your application's performance may suffer, no matter how well your application is written. There are some paradigms in OpenGL, however, which have minimizing driver overhead in mind - you don't always need Vulcan for a high-performance renderer.

Comment: @HopelesDeveloper: If you want to use both, then learn both and learn, when to use which. Finally, there are some key aspects of Vulkan, like proper multi-threading support or pluggable validation layers, that have been considered when designing the API. OpenGL in its current form doesn't have this luxury and needs to be extended or introduce a hard break at some point in its evolution.

Comment: @thokra If the graphics card is bad then the API can't affect it and the graphics are bad, right?

Comment: @HopelesDeveloper: You're using vague terms here. What's a 'bad' graphics card? What's 'graphics quality'? The graphics card either supports API X version Y or does not. If it does then the graphics 'quality' is the one you programmed. If it doesn't then it simply won't be able to run your code.

Comment: @HopelesDeveloper: "*But if garpichs are same then wyh people using different API's ?!*" Why are people using C and C++ when C#, Java, and Swift exist? Because those languages offer different features and different performance characteristics, even though they're running on the exact same CPU and system as the others.

Comment: @ybungalobill I mean Can we make graphics of a game like Doom 2016 with both APIs?

Comment: @HopelesDeveloper: Yes. As evidenced by the fact that *they did!* Doom 2016 has a Vulkan port.

Comment: @NicolBolas Doom 2016 has vulkan port.BUT is it developed with vulkan or opengl ? Can we do same grapichs with opengl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit broad, but it cannot hurt to have The Motivation question answered.
This official video presentation discusses some of the differences: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwKGmm3lw8Q

Vulkan API is a complete rework.
It also gives the programmer more control (but doing so requires him to do more, and know more).

Because of the above any graphics application also requires **whole-hearted** rework. Otherwise the benefits won't simply manifest. I don't keep updated, but I think big engines like UE4 and Unity still work on a way how to incorporate Vulkan in a non-naive manner.

Some benefits can be seen already in benchmarks. Though not in every benchmark. Some workload is fine for OpenGL and so Vulkan cannot show any improvement. Some aplications perhaps add Vulkan support just as an afterthought, making it unfair comparison. Some Vulkan drivers optimization may not  be priority (e.g. for older GPU cards).

Main benefit of Vulkan is on the CPU side. It may manifest in other ways than FPS, such as less ventilator noise (temperature), more battery life and simply having more free CPU for other tasks.

Vulkan also gives more control to the programmer. If exploited it may also translate in other non-FPS benefits, like improving input latency and preventing hitching.

Vulkan also requires less of the driver, hopefully making it easier to optimize and GPU companies more willing to adopt it and implement it even on older cards.

Everything being the same (including the program itself as much as it can be), there should be no overall resulting image quality difference. Pixel values can differ slightly here and there though.

Comment: "*It is a bit broad, but it cannot hurt to have The Motivation question answered.*" Yes, it can. By answering broad questions, you encourage others to ask broad questions. SO gets too many of these as it stands; we don't need to encourage more.

Comment: @NicolBolas It was not **that** broad to my eyes (just possibly infinite detail/depth to answer). Discouraging newbies over every small formal non-sense is not ideal either.